# Is there a way to convert a Word document into a PDF document?

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, print-to-pdf

I have seen in [OpenOffice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenOffice.org) that I can directly save the document that I have made into a PDF file. They have given an option at the top for this job.

Can I convert or save my Microsoft Word file (.doc) directly into a PDF file?

Comment: What version of Microsoft Office are you using? Native PDF support is available in Office 2007 and above.

Answer (score 10):

Install the "Save As PDF and XPS" add-in (see *[2007 Microsoft Office Add-in: Microsoft Save as PDF or XPS](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=4d951911-3e7e-4ae6-b059-a2e79ed87041&displaylang=en)*).

Click the download button, and follow the prompts to install the software. 
All the free product help is in *[Free Word to PDF Creator](http://www.anypdftools.com/free-word-to-pdf-creator.html)*.

Answer (score 7):

You can use [PDFCreator](http://www.pdfforge.org/) or [CutePDF Writer](http://www.cutepdf.com/Products/CutePDF/writer.asp) to create printers which will effectively convert anything to PDF.

Answer (score 2):

There are some drawbacks to many of the suggested answers on this page:

- Although the [Word 2007 plugin](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=7) ([Word 2010 built-in](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/save-as-pdf-HA010354239.aspx)) is extremely useful, it does bloat file size (e.g., it ballooned my 22 KB single-page résumé into a 700 KB PDF file that exceeds the upload limit on many job/career websites -- even when selecting "optimize for web").
- [CutePDF](http://www.cutepdf.com/Products/CutePDF/writer.asp) - the free version does not preserve hyperlinks.
- [PDFCreator](http://www.pdfforge.org/) - this used to be a great program, but the recent version apparently includes malware, according to numerous reviews on the [SourceForge page](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfcreator/reviews/?sort=date&filter=all#reviews-n-ratings). (I haven't personally confirmed this.)
- [pdf995](http://www.pdf995.com/) - I like this one a lot, if you can look past the ads. However, it only preserves hyperlinks if they are formatted like a URL (e.g., "http://superuser.com")
- [pdfEdit995](http://www.pdfedit995.com/) - even quirkier than its sibling pdf995, but it DOES create PDF files with valid hyperlinks (see "Batch" tab, "Convert Open Word file to PDF"). This is the one I eventually used to create a small résumé with embedded hyperlinks.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Office on the machine, you can use COM to script it to save as a PDF.  Here's code in .NET

http://www.atalasoft.com/cs/blogs/loufranco/archive/2008/04/01/loading-office-documents-in-net.aspx

Comment: i want to do the same with just the click of a button. Like we save files in .doc/ .docx format, there is an option in open office where we can save the file as pdf. If there is not such option by default, can i download a plugin to do this for me?

Comment: What do you mean by "by default"? If you mean, built into the operating system, then use one of the pdf printers mentioned by BaconBits. You should be able to right-click on a doc or docx without opening it in Word and select Print, and one the printers'll be a pdf printer. If mean something else, please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

In Mac OS X, pull down the `File` menu, select `Print...` and click on `PDF` to save a PDF file. You can do this from any document-based application, including Office.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your version, but I think in the latest version under Windows 7 you go to menu *Save* and then you select the format PDF.