# How to convert Word to PDF without the use of a web application?

Tags: pdf, microsoft-word

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to convert a word document into pdf?](https://superuser.com/questions/269705/is-there-a-way-to-convert-a-word-document-into-pdf)

I am using MS Office 2010. I have to convert a Word file to a PDF file in my daily work, so I have to use an online web application to get it done. But, I don't want to do it each and every time. Is there any add on or any thing to integrate with Word which can help me to convert a Word file to PDF without using any online web application?

Answer (score 4):

If for some reason you can't use the built-in PDF export, look at [PDFCreator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfcreator/). It's a print driver that 'prints' to a PDF file.

Answer (score 3):

Office 2010 has a [PDF export plugin](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/save-as-pdf-HA010354239.aspx) built in (2007 needed you to install it). It's as simple as 'file' -> 'save as'.

If you had needed a more general solution, or if the built in plugin didn't work for whatever reason, you need a PDF printer like [CutePDF Writer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CutePDF) - in which case you 'print' the document as per normal, and that would let you save it as a PDF.

Answer (score 0):

Not necessary to install the 'PDF Export Plugin' as the feature is built-in to Office 2010.

> you can use Microsoft Office 2010
>   programs to save files as PDFs without
>   needing additional software or
>   add-ins.

Here's the official link: [Save as PDF](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/save-as-pdf-HA010354239.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Three ways:

1. Install a "PDF printer" software, like PDFCreator or PDF995
2. Use a software that has "Export as PDF" option, like OpenOffice/LibreOffice
3. Although you are searching for an "offline way", you can also do that without needing to upload your files: do your work in Google Docs (store files there, so you don't want to upload them). Then perform "download as PDF".

Comment: but office 2010 DOES have PDF export, as at least two other answers have suggested.

Comment: pay attention :) , I said LIKE not ONLY - I used "free" software as examples of things that do the work, but some paid software also do that.